# How to reduce product image size with quality for eCommerce website?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, file-size, compression

I have to upload alot of product images to an eCommerce website. Dimensions are now 600x600px and image size 200-300kb. I want to batch reduce the file size of these to under 70kb.

Comment: What format are you saving the images in? Also, are these photographic images?

Comment: Yes these are photographic images and jpg format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Using Photoshop go to File > Scripts > Image Processor (this is essentially the same functionality as Bridge in Lucian's answer):

[image: Image Processor Dialog]

Here are a couple of simple JPGs – both 600x600, 258kb and 274kb respectively:

[image: field. by tomatokisses on DeviantArt]

[image: Athirapally Waterfalls – Wikimedia Commons]

Here they are (after running them through the Image Processor) at 53kb and 74kb:

[image: field. wrecked]

[image: Athirapally Waterfalls absolutely destroyed]

So this does just what you asked... but as you can see they don't look too good anymore... I had to lower the quality setting to just '1' to get these results. These are useless IMO. But this method would work for someone who didn't want to reduce their file sizes quite so drastically...

**Method 2:**

Running an action to 'Save for Web' in a batch (File > Automate > Batch) as described in [this link](https://blog.stirtingale.com/use-photoshops-batch-command-quickly-save-images-web/), as provided by user244052 in the accepted answer above.

However when recording the action, in the 'Save for Web' dialog choose JPEG but then rather than using the presets and sliders as described at the above link – instead go into the little Optimize Menu flyout and choose 'Optimize to File Size':

[image: A bit of a hidden feature]

And then enter 70kb, click 'OK' and then save... This is easier than trying to hit the sweet spot by trial and error. Also the Save for Web dialog includes the option to 'Convert to sRGB' so doing it as a separate step as described at the link is not necessary.

I would also examine all of the files you wish to process and the choose one that has a roughly average file size, then record your action on that image... This way your results should roughly average 70kb.

After optimization using 'Save for Web':

[image: field. Not as wrecked]

[image: Athirapally Waterfalls not as destroyed]

Those two weighed in at 59kb and 83kb respectively, and they don't look quite as bad

**Method 3:**

For those without Photoshop there is also this online tool: [Bulk Web Resizer](https://bulk.webresizer.com)

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Useful web app]

And here are the results at the settings shown:

[image: field. Looking pretty OK]

[image: Athirapally Waterfalls – Not bad]

File sizes were reduced to 72kb and 86kb using this method.

Image sources:

- [field. by tomatokisses – DeviantArt](http://tomatokisses.deviantart.com/art/field-143783144)
- [Athirapally Waterfalls – Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Athirapally_Waterfalls.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Open the images in photoshop, then go to File -> export -> Save for Web and set the quality to about 70-80. This should give you a smaller file with a pretty decent quality.

Comment: ok fine. I want bulk images using this method(script)

Comment: I've found somthing useful: https://blog.stirtingale.com/use-photoshops-batch-command-quickly-save-images-web/

Answer (score -1):

### Use Adobe Bridge

Drop all the images into one folder, select all of these in Bridge, right click and choose 'Export to → Hard Drive'. Then you get an option when you 'Constrain to Fit' all the images to 600px and try different values in the 'Image Quality' field until you manage to get these under 70kb.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote. This is the solution here :)

Comment: Probably because Bridge no longer has this option (since CS6 I believe)... The "Output Module" for Bridge can be downloaded and installed separately but most people likely have no idea it even exists

Comment: Indeed i am using CS6 but had no idea this was removed from CC. Why would they remove this?

Comment: Not sure... According to Adobe, "This plug-in is optional; it is not officially supported."

Comment: _"Why would they remove this?"_ ... I think I found out why; they just can't get it to work properly: [Blank Output Module](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1256027) I tried to install it on CC 2017 and that's what I got